# How to calculate angle between two hyperplane?

Tags: linear-algebra, angle

all.

I'm looking for a way to calculate angle between two hyperplanes.
I've seen many answers of calculating angle between 2D planes within 3D plane, but this is not the case as described below.

Let's say two subspaces ${A}$ and ${B}$ occupy ${a}$ and ${b}$ dimensional subspace respectively within ${N}$ dimension. Then how should I calculate angle between those two subspaces? (In the case where $a+b < N$, which means that there is no intersecting hyperplane except for the origin.)

When $a+b > N$, this is the case for calculating angle between 2D planes within 3D plane, and seems it could be generalized to [Dihedral angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_angle).

I'm thinking whether the angle even exists in such case, but not sure.
Any Ideas on this?

Comment: When $a+b<N$, select the subspace spanned by the two hyperplanes, and now you have $a+b\ge N$.

Comment: I think that a *hyperplane in an $N$-dimensional space* is always an $(N-1)$-dimensional subspace (or possibly a translate of one). In other words, codimension $1$.

Comment: Anyway, how do you **define** the angle between two general subspaces? Clearing that up first gives a starting point.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane) agrees with me. In $N$ diimensions a hyperplane has dimension exactly $N-1$. If the ambient space is $\Bbb{R}^N$ *equipped with the usual inner product*, then a hyperplane is determined by the direction of its normal vector, and you can calculate the angle between those two normal verctors in the usual way.

Comment: I imagine that it's the smallest angle between two vectors in the subspaces.

Comment: @TomKern Such a definition would mean that the angle is zero whenever the two subspaces intersect non-trivially. So, for example, the angle between any two planes in 3D would be zero, because those planes intersect along a line.

Comment: @Jungwoo Have you learned about linear algebra yet? **Span** is a standard terminology.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I think I was misunderstanding the concept of hyperplane. I thought subspace and hyperplane are just same two concepts. Thank you for your notice.